# How to apply font and style to xml data through xsl template

Tags: xslt, fonts

I am trying to modify the xsl code to apply some font size and color to the content it produces but not having much success.

This is my sample xml data format

```
<xml>
<Node1 attribute1="Test1" attribute2="Test2" attribute3="Test3"></Node1>
</xml>
```

and here is the current xsl template that I have:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:jscript="http://www.url.com">

<xsl:apply-templates select="//Node1"></xsl:apply-templates>    

<xsl:template match="Node1">        
Value# 1 = <xsl:value-of select="@attribute1"/>
Value# 2 = <xsl:value-of select="@attribute2"/>
Value# 3 = <xsl:value-of select="@attribute3"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to display the content
Value #1 = Test1
Value #2 = Test2
Value #3 = Test3

with some font style and color on the content. Can someone please provide some example how can I do that? Thank you

Comment: Having `<xsl:apply-templates select="//Node1"></xsl:apply-templates>` as a child of `xsl:stylesheet` is not possible so no idea what you want to achieve there. Fonts or styling depends on the target format you are trying to create with XSLT, it is not clear whether it is HTML or XSL-FO or plain text.

Comment: @Martin, I missed part of the logic. Here are the outer lines around  the line you pointed.<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="//Node1"></xsl:apply-templates> 
</xsl:template>. Currently it is displaying in plain text and I am trying to see if I can add some font. Thanks